# GA 4 - begin_checkout value appear in GTM, but not appear in GA 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

1. image 1: code
2. image 2: page source
3. image 3: GTM > begin_checkout > data layer
4. image 4: GA > Report > Realtime > Event count by Event Name
5. image 5: Debug view for begin_checkout. value is not appear

begin_checkout event and value appear in GTM, but in GA 4, the event appear without value. I believed it contains all the parameter needed for begin_checkout as shared here (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#begin_checkout)

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

[image: image5]

Comment: Did you waited 24-48h after you created your event ?
Another hint will be to create a variable from your data layer values : https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/data-layer-variable/. It seems to be the way to send values to GA4 from GTM

Comment: We can see the event but no ecommerce related parameters. Can you show the screenshot about the `begin_checkout` tag in GTM?

Answer (score 0):

You should create event params for "begin_checkout" in GTM.
[image]